# Using apply_async with callback function for a pool of processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to understand how multiprocess pools work. In the following programing I created a pool of 4 processes.

And I call `apply_async` with a callback function that should update a list called `result_list`

```
import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool

result_list = []

def foo_pool(q): #Function for each process
    print "foo_pool" 
    if(q.qsize() > 0):
        number = q.get()
    return number * 2

def log_result(result):
    # This is called whenever foo_pool(i) returns a result.
    # result_list is modified only by the main process, not the pool workers.
    result_list.append(result)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    q = Queue.Queue()
    for i in range(4):
        q.put(i + 1) #Put 1..4 in the queue

    p = Pool(4)
    p.apply_async(foo_pool, args = (q, ), callback = log_result)
```

I realize I don't need to use a queue here. But I am testing this for another program which requires me to use a queue. 
When I run the program, the function foo_pool is not being called. The print statement `print "foo_pool"` does not execute. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly speaking, apply_async only schedule async task, but not run it. You need to call `p.close()` and `p.join()` to trigger execution or `r = p.apply_async()` and `r.get()`.

Comment: But `p.join()` and `r.get()` both block until the task is done. What's the point of `async`-schedulign the task, if you still have to wait until it's done eventually?

Comment: @FooBar The task _has_ to be done eventually. Sergey is possibly mistaken about `p.join()` triggering the _execution_ of `apply_async()` (it is not true as per my observations). But you can choose to call `p.join` only when you eventually NEED the results. Till then you can run other tasks, as opposed to waiting from the time it is called till the time it is done.